# How do I turn of ucfirst in Laravel Blade Form?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

In a Laravel blade template I have a form label "email". My client wants this to be displayed as "eMail". It is being forced to "EMail"

How do I fix this?

```
 <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('eMail') !!}
    {!! Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter is the ID. The second, optional parameter is text.

```
{!! Form::label('email', 'eMail') !!}
```

Comment: OK....How do I turn off the auto capitalization of the first character of the text?

Comment: @RogerCreasy You provide the second parameter, so Laravel doesn't try and make it up. I even gave you the code to do so...

Comment: I apologize. I did not pay attention - obviously. Sorry. And thank you!